# Creating while loop in bash that would run for specific time

Tags: bash, shell, loops, datetime

I'm interested in creating a while loop in bash `(version: 3.2.57(1)-release)` running on [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) that would run for a specific number of seconds/minutes.

## Example

For instance, I would like to create ***n*** files each with current date and time during the period of *5 seconds*.

### Approach

My loop structure would be fairly basic:

```
i=$cmd(date %ss)
j=$i + 10
while [ $i -lt $j ]
do
fileName=$cmd(cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 32)
date > $fileName
i=date %ss
done
```

## Problem

When I try to execute the script I get the following errors:

```
loop.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
loop.sh: line 1: `i=$cmd(date %ss)'
```

## Desired results:

- The `i` counter reflects seconds, the loop stops after 10 seconds
- Random `*.txt` files with current date as the sole content are created in the current working directory

Comment: Try [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) first to clean up the syntax issues that don't require human feedback

Comment: @thatotherguy I tried and got another error, post updated.

Comment: Here's how to assigning command output to a variable: `var=$(mycommand)` e.g. `var=$(date +%s)`

Comment: @Konrad, SO is such a fast paced forum that I normally do much more reading of posts then answering, even if I know the answer the core group always post so fast I don't get a chance to. Anyway, while I was able to help you I wanted to say I learned something new with the method you chose to get the `fileName` and have added your technique to my code library. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will yield what you stated under "Desired results".

```
#!/bin/bash

i="$(date +%s)"
j="$(( i + 10 ))"

while [ $i -lt $j ]; do
    fileName="$(cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd 'a-f0-9' | head -c 32)"
    date > "${fileName}.txt"
    i="$(date +%s)"
done
```